# Как правильно передать функцию в функцию в питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть метод

```
def start(self, func, serv):
        func(serv)
```

я пытаюсь передать в него функцию таким образом

```
serv.start(main, serv)
```

мне выдает ошибку

```
AsyncServer.py:28: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited
  func(serv)
```

Как мне правильно передать функцию в качестве аргумента ?

Comment: У вас там asyncio как-то участвует, уточните как именно. И странно, что вы в метод объекта serv передаёте его же параметром. Зачем, если в self он и так у него есть? Что-то непонятно.

Comment: @CrazyElf ,Это асинхронный сервер, я хочу передать в качестве события для asincio функцию с параметрами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def func1():
    print(1)
def funcmain(func):
    func()
funcmain(func1)
```

Comment: Вопрос именно в том, как передать функцию с параметрами

Comment: @DenverToha через functools.partial